# function to return something x amount of times,specified by a parameter?

Tags: javascript

I have a function which returns an html element like `addSpan(times)`,is there a way to return this element as many times as specified in the parameter `items` ?

vanilla js is welcomed!

```js
function addSpan(times){
 const span = `<span>This is a span</span>`
 
 return span
}

$("body").append( addSpan(2) ) //is supposed to add 2 spans
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `\`<span>This is a span</span>\`.repeat(2)`.

Comment: @ Sebastian Simon
Wow,simple.

Answer (score 1):

Please use Array.map() function.

```
function addSpan(times){
  const spans = [...Array(times)].map(val => "<span>This is a span</span>").join('')
  return spans
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield)

```js
function* addSpan(times){
  for(var i=0; i < times; i++){
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.innerText = "Some text" ;
    yield span;
  }
}


for (let element of addSpan(2)) {
  $("body").append(element)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Possible.

Like this:

```
function addSpan(count)
{
   let result = "";
   for (var i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
     result += "<span>This is a span</span>";
   }
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need loop until you reach the count and return spans.

```js
function addSpan(times){
 let spans = "";
 const span = `<span>This is a span</span>`;

 for (let i = 0; i < times; i++){
    spans += span;
 }
 
 return spans;
}

$("body").append(addSpan(2));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```